# Download File XML with Spring boot

Tags: file, spring-boot, download

I'm trying to download files with a React front end, but the method in the controller doesn't download it

The method works because it doesn't launch any exception and the byte array works, but when I close the streams the download does not happen

```
public void downloadFile(@PathVariable("numeroOfferta") String numeroOfferta, @RequestParam(value="file") String file, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {


    String filePathToBeServed = 
    File fileToDownload = new File(filePathToBeServed + file);

    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+file);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    try(FileInputStream in =  new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        while ((in.read(buffer, 0, 4096)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, 4096);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
```

NumeroOfferta is just a String that I need to go inside folders and file contains the name of the file I send from the web page.

I can't understand why it doesn't download the file I choose despite the method works. Thank you for every answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use Spring MVC ResponseEntity:

```
public void downloadFile(@PathVariable("numeroOfferta") String numeroOfferta, 
                         @RequestParam(value="file") String file) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(file, file);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filePathToBeServed + file).toPath());
    return new ResponseEntity(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

}

That's it.

Comment: setContentType does not accept String values, are you sure I need to use headers and not resource?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't saw that. I updated my answer. But why do you return application/octet-stream and not appcliation/xml?

Comment: I return OCTET STREAM because I don't know LOL, I'll try with XML. Thanks a lot

Comment: sorry if I bother you, your solution works so thanks for that, but I still have a problem. Infact the file that i download is corrupted, do you know any possibilities that corrupt the file? I need to download xlsm files and i use "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12" in the content type

Comment: How do you load the file into your class?

Comment: I use a path to take the file(i have a folder in the file system), the problem is when i Download the file i think because in the front end i take the response and i go to download the file

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: I create a String with the path and then i create a File with it. I just notice that when the response entity give me back the data in the web page the file i want to donwload is almost the double of the original one. Is it normal? sorry for all this questions but it's my first time on a download request

Comment: How do you download it?

Comment: I send from the web page the file name that i want to download, i create a byte array with it and send back to the web page where i take the response. I think that is there the error. I use react, i'll leave my code here if you want to take a look:
 const url = window.open(); const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute("download", "Template.xlsm");
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
The problem is that the server send the correct size of the file when it arrives in the web page it has almost the double

Comment: So when you enter the download url in the browser it works?

Comment: I can't use a download url i make a call to the back end where i take the path to the file and elaborate it and finally give back a response entity, everything works but the response has more KB than the original file

Comment: ok i solved it, the reason was that the method in the back end was sending to the web page a rappresentation of the byte array so he couldn't resolve the conversion of the byte(he was sending integers) so now i send to the web page a list of integers so he can take it and convert it and download the file